Concurrent Api call to OpenAI is returning empty response
I need to process a batch of video items, format them, and call an asynchronous API to get additional data in a YAML format. However, I'm encountering an issue where the API responses are mostly empty, despite the tasks completing successfully. Below is the relevant code.
var fetchTasks = videos.Select(async item =>
{
    try
    {
        var formattedItem = new VideoItem
        {
            Title = item.Title,
            Subtitle = _extractService.GetCleanSubtitle(item.Subtitle ?? ""),
            Description = _extractService.GetCleanSubtitle(item.Description ?? ""),
        };

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(formattedItem.Subtitle) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(formattedItem.Description))
        {
            _logger.LogWarning($"Video {item.Id} has empty subtitle or description. Marking as not processed.");
            item.NotProcess = true;
            return new { item, processStatus = false, request = string.Empty, response = (string)null };
        }
        else
        {
            var builder = new RequestBuilder(formattedItem).WithYamlFormatPath(yamlPath);
            var yamlRequest = builder.Build();

            _logger.LogInformation($"Built YAML request: {yamlRequest}");

            var response = await _apiService.CallApiAsync(yamlRequest);

            _logger.LogInformation($"Response for video {item.Id}: {response}");

            return new { item, processStatus = true, request = yamlRequest, response };
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Error fetching details for video {item.Id}: {ex.Message}");
        return null;
    }
});

var fetchedDetails = (await Task.WhenAll(fetchTasks)).Where(result => result != null);

CallApiAsync Method
public async Task<string> CallApiAsync(string response)
{
    try
    {
        var completionResult = await _openAiService.ChatCompletion.CreateCompletion(new ChatCompletionCreateRequest
        {
            Messages = new List<ChatMessage>
            {
                ChatMessage.FromSystem("You are a helpful assistant."),
                ChatMessage.FromUser(response)
            },
            Model = Models.Gpt_3_5_Turbo,
        });
        if (completionResult.Successful)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(completionResult.Choices.First().Message.Content);
            return completionResult.Choices.First().Message.Content;
        }
        return "";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log or handle exception as neede
        Console.WriteLine($"Error calling ChatGPT API: {ex.Message}");
        throw;
    }
}

After the task has been completed to process the response.
foreach (var item in fetchedDetails)
{
    var video = item.video;
    var request = item.request;
    var response = item.response;
     var dbResponse = new Response
     {
         Request = request,
         YtVideoId = item .Id,
         Response = response
     };
}

Here while saving the response to the database I am often getting the item.response as empty string ("").

When I put breakpoint and debug in can see the empty string "".
It seems like the call to api has been started but not awaited properly within the batch. The tasks appear to complete without waiting for the response from CallApiAsync.
Does it might be the issue that
var completionResult = await _openAiService.ChatCompletion.CreateCompletion(new ChatCompletionCreateRequest

this code from https://github.com/betalgo/openai/blob/master/OpenAI.SDK/Managers/OpenAIChatCompletions.cs could be the reason of empty response?
How can I refactor this code to wait to the external API call to get the response correctly and process it in parallel?

item is not null, the response in item is empty, I have updated my code. with your question i realized may be CallApiAsync is returning empty?

You should remove all of our try/catch blocks and see what the debugger does for you.

i did, and still the same, when i put the CallApiAsync outside the task.when block then the responses are not empty, but putting inside the task block causing this issue.

Your issue might be related with the return ""; in your code.

when i move the CallApiAsync outside the task block, there is no such empty return. But  why it return "" empty when inside task block?

Essentially what you are asking us is to tell you why the completionResult.Successful is true is one case and false in another. Without specific knowledge of the API that you are using (_openAiService.ChatCompletion.CreateCompletion), we can't answer your question. Could you include in the question a link to the online documentation of this API?

If you read the documentation, you might find that the _openAiService.ChatCompletion.CreateCompletion API is not intended for, and doesn't support, concurrent use.

updated my question with the github link

You could try using a dedicated OpenAIService instance for each individual asynchronous operation, instead of using the same _openAiService for all operations, and see if it makes any difference.

didn't help, i run with 50 records counting just 20 request i got more than 12 as empty...

Apart from the Successful property, is there any other property that gives more information about why the operation was not Successful?

found the reason, Rate limit reached for gpt-3.5-turbo in organization on tokens per min (TPM): Limit 60000, Used 57140, Requested 4647. Please try again in 1.787s. Visit https://platform.openai.com/account/rate-limits to learn more. which means the chatgpt won't allow concurrent operation.

You could consider posting your previous comment as a self-answer, to help other people who might have the same problem. Since your question is API-specific, you might want to add a specific tag in the question (if available), or edit the title and mention the specific library or API.

Thank you for helping me debug this issue.

In case you need a RateLimiter component, you can find one here.

The reason for the empty value on response was caused by Open Ai itself.
I was getting the following error while making the API call, which I hadn't noticed at first.

Rate limit reached for gpt-3.5-turbo in organization on tokens per min
(TPM): Limit 60000, Used 57140, Requested 4647. Please try again in
1.787s. Visit platform.openai.com/account/rate-limits to learn more.

Which means technically It won't allow concurrent operation.
